# What is the maximum file size that we can upload to server using uploadify?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, .net-4.0, uploadify

I had developed MVC2 ASP.NET application using .NET 4.0 and the maximum file that i can uploaded using uploadify? My requirements is to upload utmost 20 gb of file maximum is that possible?

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about uploadify, but http uploads (at least on IIS) have a limit of 5 MB per file.  We discovered that uploading files larger than 5 MB (in an MVC 2 app hosted on windows server 2008) will result in no file data being posted to the server.

I would assume that because uploadify is just a jquery library, that the 5 MB inherent limit applies.

According to [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327659), you can increase this limit ([IIS7](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits)).  But, you should be careful because it means that your server will be accepting very large requests, which can increase your vulnerability to ddos attacks.

Some documentation says the IIS 7 limit is 30MB, but I am positive we were encountering a 5 MB limit for image file uploads that was not self-imposed.

If you need to push that large of a file up to the server, you may want to look at using FTP instead.

Comment: I uploaded more than 3.5 gb of file using uploadify